# How do I set the default build controller for TFS team builds

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017

I just set up a new Build controller (TFS 2017 although we're still stuck with XAML builds) and when I kick off a build I want the window (see below) to default to the new controller. But it still defaults to the old controller (or nothing right since I deactivated the old server):

[image]
[image]

Anyone know how I can do this? I've googled this thoroughly and found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you should change your default build controller by:

"Right click" on the build definition, 
"Edit Build Definition", 
on the "Build Defaults" set the new build controller, so once you queue up a new build this would be chosen as a default one. Similar to the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how I missed that!